# Wireguard routing from wg1 to wg0

Tags: wireguard

I have two networks configured with Wireguard. wg0 is for servers and wg1 for VPN users. When a VPN user on wg1 wants to reach the wg0 network, the packets should be router over one of the wg0 servers (the VPN gate).

wg0.conf on VPN gateway and on all servers with wg0 interface

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.1.0.15
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = privatekey1

# node23
[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey
AllowedIps = 10.1.0.23
Endpoint = node23.fqdn:51820

# node24
[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey
AllowedIps = 10.1.0.24
Endpoint = node24:51820

# node25
[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey
AllowedIps = 10.1.0.25
Endpoint = node25.fqdn:51820
...
```

wg1.conf on VPN gateway

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.100.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51810
PrivateKey = privatekey2

PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# user1    [Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey
AllowedIps =  10.100.0.2/32
...
```

And this is the users wg1.conf (actually wg0 because they don't have a 10.1.0.0 address)

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.100.0.2/32
ListenPort = 21841
PrivateKey = myprivatekey

[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey
EndPoint = vpngate.fqdn:51810
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0

PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

So, on the VPN gate itself I can run `curl -v http://10.1.0.23/` and I'm getting a response within the wg0 network. Ping works to. I can reach all servers within the network. The same with wg1-client and wg1-server. Also I can browse the internet via the VPN gate. But when I try to call from my wg1-client a wg0-server like `curl -v http://10.1.0.23/` which should be route (I think) thru the vpn-gate and from there via wg1 -> wg0 there is no response.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading WireGuard's [Cryptokey Routing](https://www.wireguard.com/#cryptokey-routing) explanations:

> In the server configuration, each peer (a client) will be able to send
> packets to the network interface with a source IP matching his
> corresponding list of allowed IPs. For example, when a packet is
> received by the server from peer gN65BkIK..., after being decrypted
> and authenticated, if its source IP is 10.10.10.230, then it's allowed
> onto the interface; otherwise it's dropped.

=> An *incoming* address must be in the `AllowedIPs` to be associated to the cryptokey defined in Peers and allowed.

> In the server configuration, when the network interface wants to send
> a packet to a peer (a client), it looks at that packet's destination
> IP and compares it to each peer's list of allowed IPs to see which
> peer to send it to. For example, if the network interface is asked to
> send a packet with a destination IP of 10.10.10.230, it will encrypt
> it using the public key of peer gN65BkIK..., and then send it to that
> peer's most recent Internet endpoint.

=> Likewise, an *outgoing* address must be in the `AllowedIPs` so the correct cryptokey and its Peer current remote endpoint can be selected.

When the client runs `curl -v http://10.1.0.23/`, outgoing packets do:

```
10.100.0.2  ----> ✔ 10.100.0.1 ==> 10.1.0.1  ----> ❌ 10.1.0.23
        wg0       wg1                    wg0       wg0
client                     gateway                   server
```

10.100.0.2 is not in server's *wg0*'s `AllowedIPs` for the gateway Peer entry so the packet is dropped.

Likewise if a server attempted to reach the client (with its route correctly configured to use *wg0*), it wouldn't find a matching Peer for the destination address so would receive an error when sending (the error, as an error returned by a network syscall, is probably specific to WireGuard: `ENOKEY` (Required key not available)).

So if clients are all in 10.100.0.0/24, they must appear in each server's configuration on the Peer section for the gateway, in the `AllowedIPs` entry. So if the gateway's address is 10.1.0.1 (can't find this information in OP), the servers should all include something similar to:

```
# gateway
[Peer]
PublicKey = pubkey
AllowedIPs = 10.1.0.1,10.100.0.0/24
Endpoint = vpngate.fqdn:51820
```

The reverse direction won't have a problem since the client is configured to associate *any* IP received on *wg0* to the gateway.

The gateway itself doesn't have to change any configuration.

Comment: Thanks - yes, that works. Additionally - I have two VPN gateways. In that case of course on every wg0 peer for VPN1/VPN2 the allowed ips must be changed AND they cannot be the same. So, any VPN gateway needs it's own network (like 10.100.0.0/24 and 10.100.1.0/24) but that's easy.

Comment: @A.B May you suggest how to solve my problem? https://serverfault.com/questions/1050765/how-to-route-traffic-from-one-wireguard-network-to-another-wireguard-network

Comment: @y2kbug I often need to reproduce questions to solve them. In your question there's Docker, Vultr and Mullvad which are too many unknowns and possible causes of additional problems: too difficult to guess immediately and correctly what's the problem.